# How can I add efficiently add many fields to a form I create in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I've got a new page new form, and I want to hook-up to some existing server-side stuff.  Right now I have this code that works, but it's sort of clunky:

```
// make a form
var OrderStatusSearchQueryForm = document.createElement("form");

// make first input 
var Operation = document.createElement("input");
Operation.name="Operation";
Operation.value="Search";
OrderStatusSearchQueryForm.appendChild(Operation);

// make second input
var SearchFieldValue = document.createElement("input");
SearchFieldValue.name="SearchFieldValue";
SearchFieldValue.value=document.formonpage.searchString.value
OrderStatusSearchQueryForm.appendChild(SearchFieldValue);

// not shown, many more inputs like the above

// set a few important values from the form on the page

OrderStatusSearchQueryForm.submit();
```

I was wondering if I could write a function that would just take the a few parameters and do the same thing.  The function would allow me to replace the above with this:

```
var OrderStatusSearchQueryForm = document.createElement("form");
stakmagic("Operation", "Search", OrderStatusSearchQueryForm);
stakmagic("SearchFieldValue", document.formonpage.searchString.value, OrderStatusSearchQueryForm);
OrderStatusSearchQueryForm.submit();
```

Comment: `I was wondering if I could write a function that would just take the a few parameters and do the same thing.` Yes.

Comment: Thanks all.  Yes, this turned out to look like a dumb question, but I got some things I hadn't thought about, like using the html parser.  What I was not clear about was in the "set a few important values" area, I needed to modify some of the values, so wasn't seeing a quick way to find them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are asking. You may have answered your own question. But if you're wanting the function, here you go:

```
function stakmagic(name, value, form) {
    var Input = document.createElement("input");
    Input.name = name;
    Input.value = value;
    form.appendChild(Input);
}
```

Comment: That's the answer to what I asked.  Thanks.  I should have been more clear that I needed to be able to get to these things created in this function.  I guess adding "Input.id = name;" in the function and then "OrderStatusSearchQueryForm.getElementById(someName)" back in the original function would do that.

Comment: Yeah, once you append the input in the function, you'll have access to the input outside of the function.

Answer (score 1):

```
 var inps = "<input name='xx' value='xx' /><input name='xx' value='xx' /> .......etc";
 <form>
     <div id='mydiv'></div> 
 </form>
 document.getElementByID('mydiv').innerHTML( inps );
```

This will create all of the elements simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously you could use functions, but why not let the HTML parser create the DOM for you, it's actually [significantly faster](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/innerhtml.html) than creating it yourself.

```
var html = '<form id="myform">' +
           '<input name="Operation" value="Search" />' +
           '<input name="SearchFieldValue" value="' +
           document.formonpage.searchString.value +
           '" /></form>';

document.getElementById("form-container").innerHTML = html;

document.getElementById("myform").submit();
```

Obviously even this is not optimal, as you have a bunch of hard coded html in your javascript. But
that problem was with your original javascript as well. Currently the cleanest and easiest way to do this is
[javascript templates](http://www.google.com/search?gcx=w&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=javascript+templating). You will be able to maintain the HTML just like it was regular HTML and use very little code to do the same thing.